# How to create steerable Edge Detection filters using Python or discard edges that don't conform to desired angle

Tags: python, opencv, canny-operator

I know how to do basic Canny edge detection using OpenCV. However I need to discard all edges that do not fall within 15 degrees of a predetermined angle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its an old question but here is the process you should use.

1]Start by filter your source image (back-ground subtract/color/etc)

2]Apply a generic Edge detector or a steerable filter or (if you want to get some really good result & are doing it for research purposes look for [Phase Strectch Transform Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_stretch_transform)

3]Save those line in a vector/whatever

4]Create a circle drawing algorithm (here is the main idea)

Your circle drawing algorithm (CDA further) will take every point returned by your edge filter.

For each point it will build  circles of a variable diameter [Dmin;Dmax] based on the max/min distance you can accept for two points be considered on the same line.

If no next-pixel are present in the circle octant corresponding to your angle, simply dismiss it.

[image: CDA Octant representation]

Once you have your lines that match your angle you can sort them by length to dismiss line probably due to noise.

You should also note that there is other methods, this method as some good aspect:

1- Its robust against noise & low quality images/video

2- Its CUDA compliant (i.e. easy to push in parallel processing).

3-Its fast and roughly more accurate than most *basic* line detectors.